# Define method implementation in mock object using Moq with return type

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, moq

My question is based on the **accepted answer** given on following thread:

[Define method implementation in mock object using Moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6834126/define-method-implementation-in-mock-object-using-moq)

In this example RequestSenderHelpers.Send() has a return type of "void". How do I make it work if the return type (of the implementation/defined method) is int, or any other type?

Comment: @mashet Basically, I want to setup the callback method as in the following line:  

sender.Setup(s => s.Send(It.IsAny<HttpWebRequest>(), It.IsAny<AsyncCallback>(), It.IsAny<object>())).Callback<HttpWebRequest, AsyncCallback, object>(RequestSenderHelpers.Send);  

Since Send() now returns a value, I will get an error message like "void Send(...) expected"  
  
Thanks

Comment: Following is my workaround to accomplish what I wanted to do. I believe I cannot specify a return type using Callback() method because it takes Action<> as parameter instead of Func<> that supports return types  

    sender.Setup(s => s.Send(It.IsAny<HttpWebRequest>(), It.IsAny<AsyncCallback>(), It.IsAny<object>())).Callback<HttpWebRequest, AsyncCallback, object>((request, callback, obj) =>RequestSenderHelpers.Send(request, callback, obj));

Comment: That's right. If you want to return a value, you must use Func instead of Action. Action is only for void methods. Regards ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var result = x.Send(It.IsAny<HttpWebRequest>(), It.IsAny<AsyncCallback>(), It.IsAny<object>());
Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(yourTypeHere));
```